# Displaying Musical Unicode Symbols in iOS UI with Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, unicode, uilabel

I am currently developing an iOS app that works a lot with musical symbols. the symbols I would like to use are found on this page:

http://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/musical-symbols/

I am trying out a few examples like assigning the text directly to the label. So this is what I see in Xcode's interface builder:

[image: Label seen in interface builder]

And this is what I see in the simulator:

[image: Label seen in interface builder]

I also tried assigning it programatically (Swift code):

```
label.text = "\u{1D15D}"
```

But no luck that way either. However, if I send this to the console with `println()` the note character is correctly printed in the console.

Just in case I tried with a few system fonts and the result was the same (Default, Arial, Verdana and Times New Roman)

So my question/questions would be: Am I doing something wrong? Are these characters not supported by iOS' interface elements like UILabels? Or maybe the problem is in the font?

I would appreciate some help here :) let me know if you need more information than what I provided here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with the font. Very few fonts contain the musical symbols of Unicode. The “UFO” symbols that you see are probably generic symbols for “strange” characters not present in the font. You may need to find a suitable free font and try to bundle it with your application.

A few fonts contain at least some of the musical symbols. The most commonly known of them, FreeSerif, Quivira, and Symbola are listed (with samples) at the Fileformat.info site on page [MUSICAL SYMBOL WHOLE NOTE (U+1D15D) Font Support](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d15d/fontsupport.htm). There is also the Musica font downloadable from the page [Unicode Fonts for Ancient Scripts](http://users.teilar.gr/~g1951d/). (The common musical symbols aren’t that ancient, but the font contains also Byzantine musical symbols.)

Comment: @Juan check in your link, the font is `Universalia`; also check this tweet https://twitter.com/unicodetable/status/394762746715054080

Comment: @TonyMkenu, Universalia is an obscure font, which is probably a mashup of other fonts. I have found descriptions of it only in Russian, and I have great doubts about its being legal (it may have been formed by combining fonts, some of which are free and some not).

Comment: @Juan if you want just a few simple notes, like `♩ Quarter Note` you can still use unicode `2669` ; check MUSICAL NOTE ICONS in http://www.zaposphere.com/html-icons-reference-unicode-character-list/    ...and...  @Jukka you are rock + 1  :)

Comment: Thank you, I followed the instructions [here](http://codewithchris.com/common-mistakes-with-adding-custom-fonts-to-your-ios-app/) to add the FreeSerif font to my project and it now works like a charm. @TonyMkenu Thanks, I had also thought of Universalia but I couldn't find its source so I gave up on it. And yeah, I was about to stick with the simple notes. Gladly, FreeSerif worked fine :)